# web_Config file configuration under IIS 10

Tags: c#, .net-core, web-config, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I have a site on IIS server which hosts ASP.NET REST APIs. They work on separate application pools which all have Unmanaged Code as their .NET CLR version. All .NET Core APIs .NET Core 3.1 written.

I have also installed hosting bundle, SDK, ASp.NET And Desktop SDKs as shown below.
[image: .NET Core installations]

Unfortunately the app does not work. When I investigate it seems the error is IIS/configuration related. The application I have deployed is published as follows :

[image: Publish profile details]

And the web.config is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <!-- The line below -->
            <aspNetCore processPath=".\Unity.REST.API.WM.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

With this configuration, when I try to open Configuration Manager of the site under Management tab I get the following error.

[image: Configuration error]

However if I remove the line under the "The line below" comment, I can view configuration, but I certainly need to keep that line to make my .NET Core REST API working.

I have copied all the files and config from another server and it works OK there. Is there any possible solution you can suggest?

Comment: Run a report to rule out the common issues first, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 1):

In applicationhost.config, check if you have such an entry:

```
<section name="aspNetCore" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Believe it should be under `<configuration> -> <configSections> -> <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">`

If you don't have it, try adding it and restart IIS.

Comment: Thank you. I have searched for "applicationhost.config" on drive C and found 8 instances where 5 of them had the entry but 3 did not. So I have added the line to these 3 files and made iisrestart. But unfortunately this did not fix the error.

Comment: That's weird.. It seems like an issue with the IIS hosting bundle, maybe try reinstalling it? Maybe also check Event Viewer to see if it may provide any hints as to what's going on. 

(By the way, the location of the relevant ApplicationHost.config should be `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config` )

Comment: How did you resolve this. I am having similar problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because the ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file contains a malformed or unidentified XML element. IIS can't identify the XML elements of the modules that are not installed. You can find probloem element by commenting some blocks and looking for type of error.

And you can also try to check whether URL rewrite is installed.

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite.

Comment: I have installed URLRewrite and checked Web.Config for XML errors and found no errors. Also I have copied Web.Config from another server where the same site runs without errors.

I am not sure about the ApplicationHost.config becuase I haven't checked it line by line but this server was a new installation, so I strongly doubt that there might be any errors.

Comment: You can try to copy ApplicationHost.config and Web.config from another server to the current server and try again.